# SQL CASE sub-query

Tags: sql

I have two tables, the following query to retrieve the os memory when max instance memory is unlimited and the error message:

```
--osmemory                          --instancememory
servername  osmemory                servername  instancename  instancememory
----------  --------                ----------  ------------  --------------
srva        4096                    srva        srva\insta    2048
srvb        6144                    srvb        srvb\instb    2147483647

select i.ServerName
     , i.instancename
     , case i.instance memory LIKE '2147483647' 
         then (select o.osmemory from o.osmemory
               join i.instance on o.servername = i.servername)
...
```

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I've been trying (and i'm still trying) various scripts, but with no luck.

Can somebody help?
Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: add your create table script or better to provide fiddler

Comment: select ( select o.osmemory from osmemory o where o.servername = i.servername ), i.instancename from instancememory i where i.instancememory = 2147483647;

Answer (score 0):

The error is obvious.  You are using a subquery in a context where one column and up to one row is allowed.  This is called a "scalar subquery".  One method to fix this uses an aggregation function:

```
select i.ServerName, i.instancename,
       (case i.instance memory LIKE '2147483647' 
            then (select max(o.osmemory) from o.osmemory join i.instance on o.servername = i.servername)
       . . .
```

However, that might not be your intent.

EDTI:

If I had to speculate, your problem is the `join` in the subquery.  You probably just want a correlated subquery.  This is a guess, but:

```
select i.ServerName, i.instancename,
       (case i.instance memory LIKE '2147483647' 
            then (select o.osmemory from o.osmemory where o.servername = i.servername)
       . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use Max(o.osmemory) or Max(o.osmemory) doesn't matter if the result will always 1.